# Arguments from commandline to MessageBox in pure winapi (C++ without standard libraries)

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line, casting

I was trying to make a pure WinApi program that simply takes arguments and puts the first one into MessageBoxW. However, there is a problem, as the arguments passed are put into LPWSTR array, but MessageBoxW takes in LPCWSTR. This givesme an error, and I tried everything, using reinterpret_cast, const_cast, standard C conversion, but nothing works.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    LPWSTR *argv;
    int argc;
    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);

    LPWSTR lol = argv[1];

    MessageBoxW(NULL, lol, "Test", 0);

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

The result is:

```
main.cpp(11): error C2664: 'int MessageBoxW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,UINT)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'
main.cpp(11): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Program compiled in Visual Studio 2015 using commandline:

```
cl /Os /GS- /Oi- primetest.cpp /link /fixed /nodefaultlib /safeseh:no /filealign:512 /entry:main /subsystem:console /MERGE:.rdata=.text kernel32.lib shell32.lib user32.lib
```

Those parameters allow for a small output file of 2kb, but this has nothing to do with the type conversion.

Also, the program compiles without any errors or warnings, and works, if a string literal is placed instead of "lol" variable in MessageBoxW.

Comment: `L"Test"` about *L* prefix you not listen ?

Comment: @RbMm It works normally if string literals are placed even without the L, because I tried. Here, my problem is conversion of VARIABLE not LITERAL from LPWSTR into LPCWSTR.

Comment: no any problems and `LPWSTR` fine without any errors converted to `LPCWSTR` . not need any case. this is visa versa need cast. you have problems only with basic knowledge. even not winapi but *c++*

Comment: Ohhhhhh... you're right, even in the error it says **argument 3** is the wrong type. I'm blind. Sorry. @RbMm

Comment: *"the arguments passed are put into LPWSTR array, but MessageBoxW takes in LPCWSTR. This givesme an error"* - No, it does not. The type `wchar_t*` can be implicitly converted to type `const wchar_t*`. You have mispresented your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    LPCWSTR *argv;
    int argc;
    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), 
&argc);

    LPCWSTR lol = argv[1];

    MessageBoxW(NULL, lol, L"Test", NULL);

    ExitProcess(0);

   return 0;
}
```